# Subset a data frame and always receive a data frame as the return type

Tags: r

How can I subset a data frame:

```
df  <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
```

such that I **always get a data frame back even if only one column is selected**?

Result as desired when selecting two columns:

```
class( df[,1:2] )
[1] "data.frame"
```

Result not as desired when selecting only one column:

```
class( df[,1] )
[1] "numeric"
```

Desired result when selecting one column would be equivalent to:

```
class( data.frame(a = c(1,2,3) )
```

Comment: `df[,1,drop=FALSE]`. Also, if you're using `dplyr`, dplyr functions return a data frame with class `tbl_df`, which will maintain data frame class even if you do `df[,1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify from Zheyuan Li:

```
df[1]
df[,1, drop = FALSE]
```

return a data frame with only column 1.

If you want to subset rows as well as columns, these work for me:

```
df[1:2, 1, drop = FALSE]
subset(df[1], a < 3)   
subset(df, subset = a<3, select = a)
```

Comment: Read the comments and your answer at the same time as when I was posting. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, both of these possibilities give exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for helping me understand this better!

```
df[1]

df[,1,drop=FALSE]
```